# Casting a C# DynamicObject to an arbitrary type

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

I am trying to write a nice consumer API for a convention-based config binder in c#. `ConfigManager.GetSection(...)` returns an object, so I want to return a dynamic object, that when cast to the required type invokes a mapper.

Is there any way in C#4+ to create a dynamic class that can handle an invocation upon having an explicit cast applied to it?

e.g.

```
MyConfig config = (MyConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("some/section");
```

In this case, the dynamic object from the ConfigurationManager would be invoked by the cast to perform some config magic (I have solved that bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DynamicObject` has an override-able [TryConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert.aspx). When the `DynamicObject` subclass is cast (or implicitly converted for an assignment) TryConvert is invoked, and you can get dynamic details about the invocation from the `binder` parameter before returning your result.

> The binder.Type
>   property provides the type to which the object must be converted. For
>   example, for the statement (String)sampleObject in C#
>   (CType(sampleObject, Type) in Visual Basic), where sampleObject is an
>   instance of the class derived from the DynamicObject class,
>   binder.Type returns the String type. The binder.Explicit property
>   provides information about the kind of conversion that occurs. It
>   returns true for explicit conversion and false for implicit
>   conversion.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that before asking (implemented every virtual method of DynamicObject) and just saw exceptions being raised - turns out they were first chance exceptions and I was rage quitting before TryConvert was being called!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of projects that deals with your need.

Check out [AutoConfig](http://autoconfig.codeplex.com/) for example.

Comment: Thanks - This project is partially a jolly, but it will also do more than AutoConfig - e.g. supporting arbitrarily complex object graphs, collections and custom binders (and POCOs)

Comment: In case you are interested, I finished this project - http://www.github.com/spadger/simple-config